# Terraform always tries to replace gcp compute instance without changes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

Good morning

I am having a problem with my terraform code. I have defined two gcp compute instances in the following way inside a specific module:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "dev_machine" {
  name = "dev-machine-${var.tag}"
  deletion_protection = true
  machine_type = "e2-standard-2"

  boot_disk {
      initialize_params {
        image = "ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/ubuntu-pro-2004-lts"
        size = 200
      }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = var.vpc.name
    subnetwork = var.subnet.name
    access_config {
      
    }
  }

  tags = ["dev-vm-${var.tag}"]
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "dev_machine-minor" {
  name = "dev-machine-minor-${var.tag}"
  deletion_protection = true
  
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"

  boot_disk {
      initialize_params {
        image = "ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/ubuntu-pro-2004-lts"
        size = 30
      }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = var.vpc.name
    subnetwork = var.subnet.name
    access_config {
      
    }
  }

  tags = ["dev-vm-${var.tag}"]
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "ssh_access" {
  name = "allow-ssh-access-${var.tag}"
  network = var.vpc.name

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports = ["22"]
  }

  source_ranges = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
  target_tags = ["dev-vm-${var.tag}"]
}
```

The variables are defined in the following way:

```
variable "vpc" {
  description = "vpc to deploy instance"
}

variable "subnet" {
  description = "subnet to deploy the subnet"
}


variable "tag" {
  description = "general project tag"
}
```

Everything works as expected when I run the command 'terraform apply', but if I run it again it always states that the instances must be replaced, even if I did not make any changes to the code. When I connect to the instance via ssh, I notice that everything was wiped out.

This is the output from 'terraform plan' with no changes to the code:

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.dev_environment.google_compute_instance.dev_machine must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_compute_instance" "dev_machine" {
      ~ cpu_platform         = "Intel Broadwell" -> (known after apply)
      ~ current_status       = "RUNNING" -> (known after apply)
      ~ deletion_protection  = false -> true
      - enable_display       = false -> null
      ~ guest_accelerator    = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                   = "<id with project>" -> (known after apply)
      ~ instance_id          = "<instance id>" -> (known after apply)
      ~ label_fingerprint    = "<label fingerprint>" -> (known after apply)
      - labels               = {} -> null
      - metadata             = {} -> null
      ~ metadata_fingerprint = "<metadata fingerprint>=" -> (known after apply)
      + min_cpu_platform     = (known after apply)
        name                 = "dev-machine-pweather"
      ~ project              = "<project id>" -> (known after apply)
      - resource_policies    = [] -> null
      ~ self_link            = "<project id url>/instances/dev-machine-pweather" -> (known after apply)
        tags                 = [
            "dev-vm-pweather",
        ]
      ~ tags_fingerprint     = "<tag fingerprint>" -> (known after apply)
      ~ zone                 = "us-east4-a" -> (known after apply)
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ boot_disk {
          ~ device_name                = "persistent-disk-0" -> (known after apply)
          + disk_encryption_key_sha256 = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_self_link          = (known after apply)
          ~ source                     = "<project id url>/us-east4-a/disks/dev-machine-pweather" -> (known after apply)
            # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)

          ~ initialize_params {
              ~ image  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-pro-2004-focal-v20210720" -> "ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/ubuntu-pro-2004-lts" # forces replacement
              ~ labels = {} -> (known after apply)
              ~ type   = "pd-standard" -> (known after apply)
                # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
            }
        }

      + confidential_instance_config {
          + enable_confidential_compute = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ network_interface {
          ~ name               = "nic0" -> (known after apply)
          ~ network            = "<project id url>/global/networks/pweather-vpc" -> "pweather-vpc"
          ~ network_ip         = "10.0.0.17" -> (known after apply)
          ~ subnetwork         = "<project id url>/subnetworks/pweather-subnet" -> "pweather-subnet"
          ~ subnetwork_project = "<project>" -> (known after apply)

          ~ access_config {
              ~ nat_ip       = "<NAT IP> -> (known after apply)
              ~ network_tier = "PREMIUM" -> (known after apply)
            }
        }

      + reservation_affinity {
          + type = (known after apply)

          + specific_reservation {
              + key    = (known after apply)
              + values = (known after apply)
            }
        }

      ~ scheduling {
          ~ automatic_restart   = true -> (known after apply)
          ~ min_node_cpus       = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ on_host_maintenance = "MIGRATE" -> (known after apply)
          ~ preemptible         = false -> (known after apply)

          + node_affinities {
              + key      = (known after apply)
              + operator = (known after apply)
              + values   = (known after apply)
            }
        }

      - shielded_instance_config {
          - enable_integrity_monitoring = true -> null
          - enable_secure_boot          = false -> null
          - enable_vtpm                 = true -> null
        }
    }

  # module.dev_environment.google_compute_instance.dev_machine-minor must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_compute_instance" "dev_machine-minor" {
      ~ cpu_platform         = "Intel Broadwell" -> (known after apply)
      ~ current_status       = "RUNNING" -> (known after apply)
      ~ deletion_protection  = false -> true
      - enable_display       = false -> null
      ~ guest_accelerator    = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                   = "<project id url>/instances/dev-machine-minor-pweather" -> (known after apply)
      ~ instance_id          = "<instance id>" -> (known after apply)
      ~ label_fingerprint    = "<label fingerprint>" -> (known after apply)
      - labels               = {} -> null
      - metadata             = {} -> null
      ~ metadata_fingerprint = "udK04sf2kcQ=" -> (known after apply)
      + min_cpu_platform     = (known after apply)
        name                 = "dev-machine-minor-pweather"
      ~ project              = "<project name>" -> (known after apply)
      - resource_policies    = [] -> null
      ~ self_link            = "<project id url>/us-east4-a/instances/dev-machine-minor-pweather" -> (known after apply)
        tags                 = [
            "dev-vm-pweather",
        ]
      ~ tags_fingerprint     = "<tag fingerprint>" -> (known after apply)
      ~ zone                 = "us-east4-a" -> (known after apply)
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ boot_disk {
          ~ device_name                = "persistent-disk-0" -> (known after apply)
          + disk_encryption_key_sha256 = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_self_link          = (known after apply)
          ~ source                     = "<project id url>/us-east4-a/disks/dev-machine-minor-pweather" -> (known after apply)
            # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)

          ~ initialize_params {
              ~ image  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-pro-2004-focal-v20210720" -> "ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/ubuntu-pro-2004-lts" # forces replacement
              ~ labels = {} -> (known after apply)
              ~ type   = "pd-standard" -> (known after apply)
                # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
            }
        }

      + confidential_instance_config {
          + enable_confidential_compute = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ network_interface {
          ~ name               = "nic0" -> (known after apply)
          ~ network            = "<project id url>>/global/networks/pweather-vpc" -> "pweather-vpc"
          ~ network_ip         = "10.0.0.16" -> (known after apply)
          ~ subnetwork         = "<project id url>/us-east4/subnetworks/pweather-subnet" -> "pweather-subnet"
          ~ subnetwork_project = "<project>" -> (known after apply)

          ~ access_config {
              ~ nat_ip       = "<NAT IP>" -> (known after apply)
              ~ network_tier = "PREMIUM" -> (known after apply)
            }
        }

      + reservation_affinity {
          + type = (known after apply)

          + specific_reservation {
              + key    = (known after apply)
              + values = (known after apply)
            }
        }

      ~ scheduling {
          ~ automatic_restart   = true -> (known after apply)
          ~ min_node_cpus       = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ on_host_maintenance = "MIGRATE" -> (known after apply)
          ~ preemptible         = false -> (known after apply)

          + node_affinities {
              + key      = (known after apply)
              + operator = (known after apply)
              + values   = (known after apply)
            }
        }

      - shielded_instance_config {
          - enable_integrity_monitoring = true -> null
          - enable_secure_boot          = false -> null
          - enable_vtpm                 = true -> null
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 2 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  ~ vm_ip = "<VM IP>" -> (known after apply)

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.
```

I tried to review the documentation, but (to my understanding) I did not find anything that could help me. Is there something I am doing wrong or is it a bug in the provider? Thank you!

EDIT 1: Added output of 'terraform plan' command.

Comment: What does `terraform plan` show? What exactly changes?

Comment: 'terraform plan' show the exact same as 'terraform apply', it states that both instances that are declared must be replaced

Comment: Can you provide the details? Which exact attributes change?

Comment: I provided now in the description, sorry for not putting it in the first place!

Comment: Did you recently add the enable_confidential_compute?

Comment: Did someone make any changes manually?

Comment: the answer to both questions is no

Comment: According to the plan, your image name is changing and forcing a resource Delete/Create. However, you stated that no one changed anything manually, and that you did not change your config. Therefore the best guess is that the provider is modifying your argument value (perhaps because it is only semi-valid). Again however, according to the documentation at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#image your argument value is validly formatted. Therefore, this is probably a bug in the provider.

Comment: @MattSchuchard you are right, that is what is causing the problem. I decided to try and change the image name to 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-pro-2004-focal-v20210720', and now it is not requesting for the image to be deleted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the plan output, the argument value forcing a replacement is:

```
~ boot_disk {
      ...
      ~ initialize_params {
          ~ image  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-pro-2004-focal-v20210720" -> "ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/ubuntu-pro-2004-lts" # forces replacement
      }
}
```

If you are comfortable updating the value from `ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/ubuntu-pro-2004-lts` to `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-pro-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-pro-2004-focal-v20210720`, then this will prevent the resource from having a Delete/Create operation applied to it.

However, the additional question here is why your argument value for `image` is changing. If you changed the config or someone manually changed the resource's attributes, then these would cause the change. However, you stated that did not occur. The provider may be attempting to auto-correct and modify the value during validation, but according to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#image), your value is completely valid. Therefore, this is likely a bug in the provider for that resource's schema.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing Matt Schuchard answer:

Something that can be useful is to add the lifecycle Meta-Argument to ignore changes on that property that would cause the replacement (destroy/apply).

Example:

```
lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [ boot_disk ]
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html